# Data range from Mysql not considered in Entity Framework object model for properties

Tags: mysql, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
CREATE TABLE `CustomerCompanyTable` (
 `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `CompanyName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `PostCode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=400 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When an Entity data model is created for MySQL database, the range value of the columns is not considered. Hence while saving back the data to the database, it is getting truncated.

Is there a way to consider data ranges also when creating an Entity data model from database?

Comment: You should read up on Microsoft's [How to: Customize Data Field Validation in the Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488527(v=vs.100).aspx) and [How to: Validate Model Data Using DataAnnotations Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.98).aspx).